# Return to stack int2hexstr

Tags: c, stack, gdb

I am currently working on the common return to stack project and I have seen many of example online and on youtube that are very common. Yet when I try to recreate the project with the `int2hexstr()` function my results are not the same.

[Example of test string arugment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG07I.jpg)

As you can see 76 A's print to the screen along with 100 I's and 4 B's along with the shellcode.

However when I replace the `BBBB` with `int2hextr()`, My argument is simply exactly what I typed in the single quotation marks.

[Example of test string argument with address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJV0.jpg)

I am aware that my results do not print in hexadecimal like most examples in either picture but will that make a difference, as well.

Is there an alternative to use instead of int2hexstr or is there something else I need to type. Also I using a virtual machine, Debian 7.xxx

copy of code i am trying to use return 2 stack

```
char* dovuln(coonst char*s)
{   char buf[64];
    strcpy(buf, s);
    puts(buf);
    fflush(stdout);
    return strdup(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   if (argc < 2)
  {
   puts("missing argument");
   exit(1);
  }

dovuln(argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*the common return to stack project*" common in which sense. Did I miss something?

Comment: And why is the flagged C?

Comment: I used common because the way the excerise works.... I see people do it the same way. For instance, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knC3B3RKARo and http://archive.evilzone.org/tutorials/basic-linux-bof-%28introducing-gdb-peda%29/ (just two example). Also the file I am using is a c file. I pasted it above.

Comment: Sorry i just pasted it